# Obtener el elemento clicado, detectado en función de su clase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy tratando de obtener lo que es el elemento que estoy haciendo clic, pero ni idea de cómo proceder. Este es el caso concreto:

Esquema Html:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <!-- Pongamos que clico este elemento -->
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
...
```

Estoy vinculando cuando se hace clic en un elemento con el siguiente código JQuery:

```
$('.item').on('click', (event) => {
      //¿Cómo puedo obtener aquí el elemento? concreto
      myElement.animate({...}, 5000, function() {...});
});
```

¿Como podría detectar el elemento concreto que estoy haciendo clic (Y no todos los de la clase)?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Estás es StackOverflow en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o trasládala al sitio en inglés. _Hi and welcome. You are in StackOverflow in Spanish. Please, translate your question or move it to the English website_.

Comment: Tan solo debes **cambiar la función flecha por una normal** (pues la función flecha te impide usar **$(this)**) y donde pones `myElement` pones  `$(this)` y debería funcionarte.  Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Me despista cuando dices: "lo que es el elemento".
¿que quieres ?
su tipo, su clase, el elemento (para hacer cosas con el)
no tengo muy claro que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar la funcion de flecha por una función normal, pues la de flecha no reconoce el $(this) que representa el elemento clicado.

Prueba con esto:

```js
$('.item').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="item">uno
  <div class=" front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">dos
  <div class=" front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">tres
  <div class=" front"></div>
  <div class="back"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

La clave es  $(this) y attr.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp (localiza el elemento)

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp (atributo clase)

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
$( "#info" ).text('el elemento cliccado es de clase:'+ $( this ).attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item1">
  <div class="front">uno</div>
  <div class="back">dos</div>
</div>
<div class="item2"> <!-- Pongamos que clico este elemento -->
  <div class="front">tres</div>
  <div class="back">cuatro</div>
</div>
<div class="item3">
  <div class="front">cinco</div>
  <div class="back">seis</div>
</div>
<div id ="info">
info
</div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar el campo target del evento

```
$('.item').on('click', (event) => {
    $(event.target).animate({...}, 5000, function() {...});
});
```

Ahora bien, puedes ocupar "this", pero debes cambiar la función lambda por una tradicional, ya que el scope (el ambito) de las 2 son distintos

```
$('.item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).animate({...}, 5000, function() {...});
});
```